# How can we create a system in PHP such that a user can login only through the machine he has registered?

Tags: php, authentication, device, detection, device-detection

How can a specific device be allowed to access and log in?
I want my users to be able to log in only with the device they have already authenticated.
Of course, I don't mean using session (non-expiring cookie) because it will be lost after some time or by clear chach.
It should also be in such a way that this access remains after changing the IP.

For this, I first checked the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer).
Then the type of device and its operating system (Linux, Ubuntu, Windows, Android and Apple)

## ***But if a user logs in with two identical devices, the same operating system and the same browser, this code cannot figure it out.***

with the following code:

```
class Detect
{
    public static function systemInfo()
    {
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $os_platform = "Unknown OS Platform";
        $os_array = array('/windows phone 8/i' => 'Windows Phone 8',
            '/windows phone os 7/i' => 'Windows Phone 7',
            '/windows nt 6.3/i' => 'Windows 8.1',
            '/windows nt 6.2/i' => 'Windows 8',
            '/windows nt 6.1/i' => 'Windows 7',
            '/windows nt 6.0/i' => 'Windows Vista',
            '/windows nt 5.2/i' => 'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
            '/windows nt 5.1/i' => 'Windows XP',
            '/windows xp/i' => 'Windows XP',
            '/windows nt 5.0/i' => 'Windows 2000',
            '/windows me/i' => 'Windows ME',
            '/win98/i' => 'Windows 98',
            '/win95/i' => 'Windows 95',
            '/win16/i' => 'Windows 3.11',
            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' => 'Mac OS X',
            '/mac_powerpc/i' => 'Mac OS 9',
            '/linux/i' => 'Linux',
            '/ubuntu/i' => 'Ubuntu',
            '/iphone/i' => 'iPhone',
            '/ipod/i' => 'iPod',
            '/ipad/i' => 'iPad',
            '/android/i' => 'Android',
            '/blackberry/i' => 'BlackBerry',
            '/webos/i' => 'Mobile');
        $found = false;

        $device = '';

        foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) {
            if ($found)
                break;
            else if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
                $os_platform = $value;
                $device = !preg_match('/(windows|mac|linux|ubuntu)/i', $os_platform)
                    ? 'MOBILE' : (preg_match('/phone/i', $os_platform) ? 'MOBILE' : 'SYSTEM');
            }
        }
        $device = !$device ? 'SYSTEM' : $device;
        return array('os' => $os_platform, 'device' => $device);
    }

    public static function browser()
    {
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $browser = "Unknown Browser";
        $found = false;

        $browser_array = array('/msie/i' => 'Internet Explorer',
            '/firefox/i' => 'Firefox',
            '/safari/i' => 'Safari',
            '/chrome/i' => 'Chrome',
            '/opera/i' => 'Opera',
            '/netscape/i' => 'Netscape',
            '/maxthon/i' => 'Maxthon',
            '/konqueror/i' => 'Konqueror',
            '/mobile/i' => 'Handheld Browser');

        foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) {
            if ($found)
                break;
            else if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent, $result)) {
                $browser = $value;
            }
        }
        return $browser;
    }
}


print_r(Detect::systemInfo());
print_r(Detect::browser());
```

Comment: How secure does this have to be? Anything you try to do can probably be spoofed if they know how to use Developer Tools.

Comment: https://fingerprint.com/blog/browser-fingerprint-php/ is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: No. PHP in no way controls the client device, and any information received from the device can be spoofed. Yes, even if you are clever with Javascript. The more important question is "Why do you think you need this?" because we could suggest alternate approaches that are less impossible.